# Security rules in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I've database structure like

```
 appointments
     [$userId]
         [$appointmentId]
              message:"something"
              date:"14/12/2015"
 users
    [$userId]
        name: Hardik
        email: hardikmsondagar@gmail.com
```

And I'm using angularfire library of Firebase, I'm trying to restrict read operation based on uid ( means a person who created appointment only can read that). I've tried following security rule

```
{
  "rules": {
    "appointments": {
      "$userId":{
        "$appointmentId":{
         ".read": "auth.uid==$userId",
         ".write": true
        }
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "$userId":
        {
          ".read": "auth!=null && $userId === auth.uid",
          ".write": "auth!=null && $userId === auth.uid"
        }
    }
  }
```

But end up on this error
 **Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.**

I'm trying to access all the user's appointments using following code

```
 var ref = new Firebase("https://<FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/appointments/"+uid);
 $scope.appointments = $firebaseArray(ref);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set rules for the `$uid` wildcard, to read all the children.

```
"appointments": {
  "$uid":{
    ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
    ".write": "auth.uid == $uid",
  }
}
```

The `$uid` wildcard sets permissions for the entire list, whereas the `$appointmentId` wildcard sets permissions for each individual item.

But Security Rules cascade, so you only need to set the rules for the top level.

[**Read the docs on cascading for more information.**](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-cascade)

Comment: Thanks a ton. Now I understand it's the read operation I was performing in wrong way.